# Removing the specific words from a list

Tags: python

I am trying to remove specfic words from the list and also `<title>` and `<\title>` found in the text file.

I need to also remove the words contained over the list as `words=[a,is,and,there,here]`

My list `lines` consists of text as:-

`lines=` 
 `[<title>The query complexity of estimating weighted averages.</title>', '<title>New bounds for the query complexity of an algorithm that learns DFAs with correction and equivalence queries.</title>', '<title>A general procedure to check conjunctive query containment.</title>]`

Please help me to remove the words contained over the list and also

Comment: You have a list of strings and you can use [split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) or [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) at each line, Please attach some code and show the specific problem.

Comment: First show your code.

Comment: Put the words you want to remove into a second list, iterate over them and remove them in the first list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through `re.sub` function.

```
>>> lines= ['<title>The query complexity of estimating weighted averages.</title>', '<title>New bounds for the query complexity of an algorithm that learns DFAs with correction and equivalence queries.</title>', '<title>A general procedure to check conjunctive query containment.</title>']
>>> words=['a','is','and','there','here']
>>> [re.sub(r'</?title>|\b(?:'+'|'.join(words)+r')\b', r'', line) for line in lines]
['The query complexity of estimating weighted averages.', 'New bounds for the query complexity of an algorithm that learns DFAs with correction  equivalence queries.', 'A general procedure to check conjunctive query containment.']
```

`\b` before and after a word will helps to do an exact word match. `\b` called word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it more efficiently without using a regex:

```
lines = ['<title>The query complexity of estimating weighted averages.</title>',
         '<title>New bounds for the query complexity of an algorithm that learns DFAs with correction and equivalence queries.</title>',
         '<title>A general procedure to check conjunctive query containment.</title>']
words = {"a", "is", "and", "there", "here"}

print([" ".join([w for line in lines
             for w in line[7:-8:].split(" ")
             if w.lower() not in words])])


['The query complexity of estimating weighted averages.
 New bounds for the query complexity of an algorithm that learns 
 DFAs with correction equivalence queries.
 general procedure to check conjunctive query containment.']
```

If case matter remove the `w.lower()` call.Also if you are extracting the lines by parsing a webpage I suggest you extract the text from the tags before writing to a file.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should always post what you have tried so far.

Using only built in libraries:

```
for i in range(0, len(lines)-1):
    for it in range(0, len(words)-1):
        lines[i] = lines[i].replace(words[it], '')
```

Code explained by line:

1. For every item in the list 'lines', i=the item number of the current line
2. For every item in the list 'words', it=the item number of the current word in 'words'; replaces all items in word found in the current item in 'list' with ''
3. The current item in list 'lines' is change to itself without the current item in 'words'

Answer (score 0):

```
lines=['<title>The query complexity of estimating weighted averages.</title>', '<title>New bounds for the query complexity of an algorithm that learns DFAs with correction and equivalence queries.</title>', '<title>A general procedure to check conjunctive query containment.</title>']

words = [' a ', ' is ', ' and ', ' there ', ' here ', '<title>', '</title>']
```

I added spaces before and after each word you want to remove, to make sure you remove the word and not a letter, this wont cover up cases where you have commas or dots within the sentence or if the last word is in the list. Also, this is case sensitive.

After that, just do:

```
for i in words:
  for j in range(0,len(lines)):
    lines[j]=lines[j].replace(i,'')
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are starting with this (slightly fixed):

```
lines=  ['<title>The query complexity of estimating weighted averages.</title>', '<title>New bounds for the query complexity of an algorithm that learns DFAs with correction and equivalence queries.</title>', '<title>A general procedure to check conjunctive query containment.</title>']
```

And want to remove specific words / character sequences:

```
remove_words = ['a', 'is', 'and', 'there', 'here', '<title>', '</title>']
```

You could do this:

```
trimmed_lines = []
for line in lines:
    trimmed_lines.append(' '.join([w for w in line.split() if w not in remove_words]))
```

Comment: but now i get output like this `[['<', 't', 'i', 't', 'l', 'e', '>', 'T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'y', ' ', 'c', 'o', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e', 'x', 'i', 't', 'y', ' ', 'o', 'f', ' ', 'e', 's', 't', 'i', 'm', 't', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'w', 'e', 'i', 'g', 'h', 't', 'e', 'd', ' ', 'v', 'e', 'r', 'g', 'e', 's', '.', '<', '/', 't', 'i', 't', 'l', 'e', '>'], ['<'`

Comment: You shouldn't; I don't. Perhaps you're only operating on the first title, not the list of titles shown in the answer?

Comment: Don't put quotes *outside* the square brackets, they were missing *inside* the square brackets in OP.